# cytoscape.js unique node is outside the visible area

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

im using cytoscape.js to display a tree. It works perfectly when the tree has several nodes, but when my tree contains only one node, this is rendered outside the visible area. 
I can zoom out and it appers on the lower right edge of my container.

the initialization is as following:

```
call: ->
    $ loadCy = =>
      options =
        layout: {
          name: 'breadthfirst'
          # maximalAdjustments: 2
          roots: @_findRootNode()
          padding: 10
        },
        showOverlay: true
        boxSelectionEnabled: false
        minZoom: 0.5
        maxZoom: 1.5
        style: cytoscape.stylesheet().selector("node").css(
          content: "data(name)"
          "font-family": "helvetica"
          "font-size": 12
          "text-outline-width": 1
          "text-outline-color": "#888"
          "text-valign": "center"
          color: "#fff"
          width: "mapData(weight, 30, 80, 20, 50)"
          height: "mapData(height, 0, 200, 10, 45)"
          "border-color": "#fff"
        ).selector(":selected").css(
          "background-color": "#000"
          "line-color": "#000"
          "target-arrow-color": "#000"
          "text-outline-color": "#000"
        ).selector("edge").css(
          width: 2
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
        )
        elements:
          nodes: @_nodesArray()
          edges: @_edgesArray()

        ready: ->
          cy = this
          return

      $( @canvas ).cytoscape options
      return
```

does anyone had the same problem?
thanks!

Comment: Could you attach an image of the problem?  Have you tried setting the `overflow` property in your container's CSS?

Comment: Yes, here you have it
http://tinypic.com/r/2ed03mo/8

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all.  Can you post a jsbin example?